# Check if a string is valid absolute path address format

Tags: python

I have a string which contains user input for a directory address on a linux system.  I need to check if it is properly formatted and *could* be an address in Python 2.6.  It's important to note that this is not on the current system so I can't check if it is there using os.path nor can I try to create the directories as the function will be run many times.

These strings will always be absolute paths, so my first thought was to look for a leading slash. From there I wondered about checking if the rest of the string only contains valid characters and does not contain any double slashes.  This seems a little clunky, any other ideas?

Comment: Linux [filenames](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) cannot contain `\0` or `/` - that's the only restriction

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure the question has been edited since writing this but:

There is the `os.path.isabs(PATH)` which will tell you if the path is absolute or not.

> Return True if path is an absolute pathname. On Unix, that means it begins with a slash, on Windows that it begins with a (back)slash after chopping off a potential drive letter.

Comment: Note that this method does not verify that the path or file name exists, so it should be what the OP wants

Comment: I parsed the question as asking if it was formatted correctly, which is what this answer checks.